# Display a custom post type list by taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type, wp-list-categories

I need to show a list of custom post type classified by terms. The idea is something like this:

Service list:

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <a href="#">Webdesign (taxonomy term)</a>
   <ul>
     <li>Business Website A (custom post type from this taxonomy term)</li>
     <li>Business Website B (custom post type from this taxonomy term)</li>
     <li>Business Website C (custom post type from this taxonomy term)</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
   <a href="#">Illustration (taxonomy term)</a>
   <ul>
     <li>Business Illustration A (custom post type from this taxonomy term)</li>
     <li>Business Illustration B (custom post type from this taxonomy term)</li>
     <li>Business Illustration C (custom post type from this taxonomy term)</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Other service without taxonomy (if has no taxonomy, show in first level)</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried the *wp_list_pages* and *wp_list_categories*, but without success.

- Could someone give me a hint how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_posts` or `WP_Query` with taxonomy parameters:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Example with `get_posts`:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Webdesign</a>
        <ul>
<?php $items = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'webdesign'
        )
    )
) );
if( $items ){
    foreach ( $items as $item ){
        setup_postdata( $item );
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title( $item->ID ) . '</li>';
    }
} ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need a little more information on how to do. Could you help me?